Only 3 Wires going to a sub panel
I have an old Siemens sub panel (1990s) that I would like to replace soon. I took the panel cover off and and there is 3 wires (2 hots and a neutral). if I am correct, you need 4 wires (2 hots, a neutral and a ground) if it is past the main disconnect for the entire electrical system. how would I be able to fix this? add a ground rod? or would I just have to run new wires to the panel from the disconnect?
Any help is appreciated, thanks
I

What kind of conduit (basically: metal or plastic) connects the subpanel to the main panel?

Where do the heavy ground wires on the upper left and lower right of the box go? Do they connect to other heavy ground wires that connect to the main and the external grounding system? They don't appear to be assocated with any branch circuit. The upper left one does need a clamp, though.

I am fairly certain that both of them go outside.

Outside may or may not mean they connect to a grounding wire also outside that goes back to the main panel. You should figure out where they go, outside, and what they connect to.

What other breakers are out at the main disconnect?  Is it only a disconnect?

Yes it is only a 100 Amp main disconnect that turns power off before the panel its self

If the incoming conduit is/was metallic (but it looks like PVC to me in that picture) that would be the ground conductor connecting this to the main panel.
However, it is in conduit, so you can add a ground wire to it. You can also add a ground wire by a different path, but since you have conduit, might as well take advantage of it. For a 100A sub-panel you need 6 AWG aluminum or 8 AWG copper as a minimum ground conductor size.

Adding a ground rod does NOT fix it, and if it's in the same building as the main panel there's no need to add a ground rod. In a separate building you need a ground wire to the supply and a local ground (usually 2 rods at least 6 feet apart, or an UFER ground (concrete encased electrode) and a ground rod.
Legally you might be able to play the "it was correct when installed and it's grandfathered and I'm just repairing/replacing it, not upgrading it" card; but own-safety-wise that's not very smart, IMHO.

I am pretty sure that there is an attic above so I should be able to access the PVC if I need it (yes it Is PVC I double checked). What size would the ground wire have to be?

By definition, any necessary access points in a conduit must be always accessible. Of course, even if it was built and approved that way, somebody who didn't know what it was might have boxed it in somewhere.

Image credit is that I went looking for a previous post with this image, didn't find the post, but found the image on imgur directly, so I used it.

Shouldn't the branch circuit grounds also be removed from the neutral bars (insulated from the box) and connected to the ground bar (attached to the box) in the lower right side of the box?

The main disconnect outside may not matter
Yes, as a general rule, you run 3-wire before the main breaker and 4-wire past the main breaker. But "main breaker" does not mean "first disconnect past the meter".  It's possible to disconnects (including those which are breakers) which do not count as the main breaker/service disconnect.
Take a look at the labeling requirements in NEC 230.85.
So if an extra disconnect can be before the main breaker, what else can be?   This is covered at NEC 230.82.

Solar
Surge suppressor
Generator interlock
Energy storage equipment
A few others

So, as long as there aren't any other loads out there, you'd be in the clear simply to label the outdoor disconnect per NEC 230.85, "Emergency Disconnect / Not a Service Disconnect".
I might make the argument that EV charging sounds like energy storage equipment, because of how it actually works… but I would not count on every inspector agreeing.
